# Is it possible to have Windows 7 installer files and Ubuntu installer files on the same bootable USB drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb-drive

I would like to know whether it is possible to have Windows 7 installer files and Ubuntu 12.04 installer files on the same bootable USB drive so that if I choose to boot a PC with such a USB drive, I will get the option to install either Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

Perhaps a USB drive can have two bootable partitions, one with Windows 7 setup files while the other can have Ubuntu 12.04's setup files. On booting with such a drive, one gets a boot screen which lets you install either of the two or both at different times.

Is such an arrangement possible? Can this be done?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer), is the successor to MultibootISOs. It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc cloning, diagnostic tools, and more. Contrary to MultiBootISO's which used grub to boot ISO files directly from USB, YUMI uses syslinux to boot extracted distributions stored on the USB device, and reverts to using grub to Boot Multiple ISO files from USB, if necessary.<sup>1</sup>

To [Download](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)</sup>

Comment: I'll try out Yumi. Will report back if I have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Yumi is great. I couldn't manage to put my current Windows ISO on the USB, but I discovered that my FAT32 drive cannot support a 4.2GB iso image. I guess I am out of luck on that one.

Answer (score 0):

To create multiboot live-USB keys, you can use [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) or [MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2).